# Inject shared library into a running process

Tags: c++, linux, qt, shared-libraries, code-injection

I just started to learn injection techniques in Linux and want to write a simple program to inject a shared library into a running process (app using QT). However, after a couple of hours research, I couldn't find any complete example.

Why dlsym can't find qt_startup_hook?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>


void hello()
{
    printf("Call hello\n");
    void *func = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "qt_startup_hook");

    if (!func) {
        printf("Error\n");
    }
}
```

Gdb:

```
b main
run
call dlopen("/linux-inject/sample-library.so",2)
>> $1 = 108781344
call hello()
>> Call hello
>> Error
```

Gdb found qt_startup_hook:

```
info functions qt_startup_hook
>> Non-debugging symbols:
>> 0x00007ffff7b0ae40  qt_startup_hook
```

Comment: Try RTLD_DEFAULT?

Comment: It is possible that for RTLD_NEXT to work properly you have to define `qt_startup_hook` in your lib.

Comment: I assume you're using LD_PRELOAD to preload your version of `qt_startup_hook`, and then offloading it to the real `qt_startup_hook`?
 If you haven't defined your own `qt_startup_hook` then `RTLD_NEXT` won't find the real one (ie: the *next* one), since your own one isn't the *first* one. See [here](http://samanbarghi.com/blog/2014/09/05/how-to-wrap-a-system-call-libc-function-in-linux/) for more details.

Comment: If you don't want to use LD_PRELOAD you can actually inject your own function into a dynamically linked library (eg Qt) using a utility called [elfhook](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70302/Redirecting-functions-in-shared-ELF-libraries)

Comment: Ok it's working but now how i can find function in other namespace like foo::bar::baz ?